# Use localStorage to display the last n pages visited

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to capture at maximum the last 3 pages visited, and store the url and other string data such as title and description.

local storage seems the best bet, but what method should I use to save the data?

If I create an array i saw on SO how to push that as an object

```
var testObject = { 'url': window.location.href, 'location': 'Japan', 'desc': 'some brief description text' };
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));
```

but how could I store/update (in this example) the most recent 3 of these arrays in localStorage, and then retrieve all 3 in order of last visited to be listed out on a page?

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of the built-in `shift` and `push` methods:

- `shift`: it removes the last element from an array
- `push`: it adds one or more elements to the end of an array

The first time a page is requested, save your object in an array and place it in your `localStorage`:

```
var items = [{ 'url': window.location.href, 'location': 'Japan', 'desc': 'some brief description text' }];
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(items));
```

On ongoing call, test the `length` of the array and `shift` or `push` your new item accordingly:

```
var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testObject'));
if(items.length === 3) {
  items.shift(); //the first item in the array is removed. So length is 2
}

items.push(your new item); //length is 3
```

Finally save your new items into the storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(items));
```

You could create a `find` method to look for what you need to work with:

```
var find = function(arr, url) {
  return arr.filter(function(el) {
    return el.url === url;
  })[0];
}

var item = find(items, 'http://url.com');
```

Note that `localStorage` is part of *ECMAScript 5th edition*. So provide a polyfill for browsers that don't support it. If cross-browser compatibility is required ensure that both shift and push are present (though pretty standard methods).

See Mozilla MDN for more information about Array:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Thanks, although I am not sure how to pull out specific values once stored - I assume I need to get the url of the object within the array?:

retrievedObject: [Array[1], Array[1], Array[1]]
0: Array[1]
0: Object
desc: "desc"
id: "46"
location: "Japan"
other: "more text"
...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mUUpD/

perhaps I'm doing something wrong (it's definitely beer-o-clock)- I'm getting undefined

Comment: currentPageîtem must be a single object, not an array. You store an arrayItems containing n items. http://jsfiddle.net/mUUpD/1/