# How to Get last working page in my application while log in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

i have use angular 6 as a front end and .net web api as a back end.
In my application 4 pop(Merged) is there.if user log in the application open the second pop up then close the browser window or log out the application.how can i get last working page with data after log in.

Comment: You should keep the information you need in the **cookies** or **localStorage** at browser. After the user visits your site, you must manage this information and redirect the ideal pages.

Comment: you can reference more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779476/use-localstorage-to-display-the-last-n-pages-visited?rq=1